# How to split numbers in pandas column into deciles?

Tags: pandas

I have a column in pandas dataset of random values ranging btw 100 and 500.

I need to create a new column 'deciles' out of it - like ranking, total of 20 deciles. I need to assign rank number out of 20 based on the value.

- 10 to 20 - is the first decile, number 1
- 20 to 30 - is the second decile, number 2

  ```
    x = np.random.randint(100,501,size=(1000)) # column of 1000 rows with values ranging btw 100, 500.

  df['credit_score'] = x

      df['credit_decile_rank'] = df['credit_score'].map( lambda x: int(x/20) )

      df.head()
  ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use integer division by `10`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'credit_score':[4,15,24,55,77,81],
})

df['credit_decile_rank'] = df['credit_score'] // 10
print (df)
   credit_score  credit_decile_rank
0             4                   0
1            15                   1
2            24                   2
3            55                   5
4            77                   7
5            81                   8
```